# Help replacing a bathroom vanity light fixture with no ground wire in metal clad cable

Tags: bathroom, grounding, light, vanity

Attempting to replace a bathroom vanity light fixture, removed the previous fixture and found a rough hole in the drywall with metal clad cable containing only 2 wires (yellow and white) - no ground wire observed and no junction box.

I have been trying to look up the proper way to install the new fixture safely, and am currently under the impression I should install a metal (old work) junction box (as the cable is metal clad) using a connector along with an anti-short bushing and then install the new fixture.

Is this a correct plan and what should I do about the lack of a ground wire?

[image]

Comment: Based on (a) colors yellow/white instead of standard black/white and (b) amount of space around the wires, that looks like flexible metal conduit rather than armored cable. Which also means, but I'm not 100% sure so just a comment and not an answer, that the metal is a valid ground *within certain constraints*. I'd check continuity metal to white neutral - if it shows good (close to 0 ohm) then with a properly attached metal box I think you're all set.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-8-in-Flexible-Metal-Conduit-FMC-Screw-In-Connector-90440/100139454 you screw that into the cable, then the entire metal box becomes the ground. (There are different sizes, I picked a random one.)

Answer (score 3):

Task completed.

1. Tested flexible Metal Conduit for grounding, and it was grounded. (written method and video tutorial [here](https://allcoasthomeinspections.com/how-to-tell-if-metal-box-is-grounded/))
2. Used a "3/8 in. Flexible Metal Conduit (FMC) Screw-In Connector" to secure conduit to a "RACO 1-Gang Gray Metal New Work/Old Work Standard Octagonal Ceiling/Wall Electrical Box ", then secured box to a stud. *Because the connector separates the wires from the edges of the conduit in its basic construction, I did not use a plastic bushing in this case*.
3. Checked the box grounding with multimeter and confirmed.
4. Finished with typical ground-to-box, white-to-white, and black(yellow)-to-black connections using appropriately sized wire nuts.

Comment: Well done! Note that if you connect "hot-to-hot" and "neutral-to-neutral", you get around the pesky black/yellow problem. When run in conduit, white & grey are neutral, green (if present) is ground, and _all other colors_ are hot.